# Is Sly Trilogy compatible with Cross-Buy?

Tags: ps3, ps-vita, the-sly-collection

Sly Trilogy was released on PS3 and now on PS Vita, I have the PS3 version and also the PS Vita.

So my question is: Can I play at Sly Trilogy on Vita if I have the PS3 version? I know it is possible for Sly Thieves In Times so maybe it is possible for Sly Trilogy

Comment: Does it show up in your download list on the vita?

Comment: Nope, and I forgot to say that I bought the PS3 version not on the PS Store before the Vita version was released, I have the "physical" version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the game itself does not say Cross-play on it in the store then it is not possible. With some cases of cross-play coming after purchase of the digital version, I am very sure that it will then work on the vita since it is not technically a different purchase and simply an update do the existing digital copy. In your case since you own the physical copy for the PS3 you would have to purchase the digital copy in order to have access to it digitally, unless there was a code given for the digital version inside of the game case, which I am doubting.

Comment: This is obviously not what I wanted to read but I think you're right

Comment: I've had many similar cases happen to me, this is going to happen a lot now since the demand for digital is going up. Happened to me for Borderlands, CoD MW2, FF13-2, and honestly a lot of others. It kinda sucks how you can't get a digital copy when you own the physical copy, it could work like emulation but people would find a way to abuse it so the companies make money off of it instead.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [description in the EU store](https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/games/the-sly-trilogy/cid=EP9000-PCSF00338_00-SLYLEU110100SHIP), the game **is** cross-buy, meaning that owning one version entitles you to the other. This is applicable to the PSN version, of course, not the disc one.